# Booting from pen drive - possible or not

Tags: usb, boot, installation, usb-flash-drive, iso-image

I have an iso file of operating system's set up.

Now, I don't have dvd burner right now.

But the alternate - 4gb pen drive is available.

If I copy entire iso file to pen drive,

Can my system boot through pend drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you worded it as "if I copy the entire iso file to the pen drive" I want to just clarify something. You do not want to copy the .iso file to the thumb drive. You need to use an utility, such as [UltraISO](http://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/), to extract the ISO contents first. It is those files that need to be on the thumb drive. Also make sure that whatever is in the root of the ISO is also in the root of the thumb drive. I have seen people copy the ISO contents into a folder on the thumb drive and then be surprised why it won't boot.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your machine.

Most computers in the past few years - Yes, but you may need to burn a operating system on there as well as the machine *may* not pick it up.

Basically, I have pretty much found that most machines I work from can just have standard ISO's expanded to USB drives and work straight away without anything extra, where as some require you to format, include system files and basically prepare it before you start to copy over any other files.

Try it, you can't break anything by just having a go! (unless you have some sort of unattend script that formats your drive!... But if you can get that far, it has probably done what you need!)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/

Similar steps will work for any other iso.

Answer (score 1):

Plain copying an ISO file to a usb drive won't always work. I'm just guessing it is a linux distribution you want to install on the usb drive.

[http://www.pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/)

On this site you can find all kind of guides how to install ubuntu, backtrack, fedora, and way more distributions on a usb pendrive.

~ Jeffrey V.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) which offers

- a set of predefined Linux distributions you can download a package for,
- and also the possibility to make you own ISO image bootable. This means, you can feed it a windows image, too.

The tool is available for Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

if this is a windows installation disc image, mount the ISO (e.g. with [WinCDEmu](http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/)) then use **[WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/)** to create a bootable USB stick. it doesn't get any easier.

> Can my system boot through pend drive?

unless you post make and model of your system, this is hard to answer, but most modern computers can boot from USB. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to write a bootable ISO to a USB drive: Just use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) - it does precisely what you are asking for.

The program is self-explanatory.

Here is a search that has links to reviews and instructions:  [Rufus search results on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=rufus%20copy%20iso%20to%20usb)